# Apache Reverse Proxy Sending Browser to Backend Directly Instead

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy-html

(**UPDATE** at the bottom for the main question, below may be superfluous details)

I'm having an interesting problem with Apache not reverse proxying as expected.

Basically, what's happening is when I click a link on my website that goes to the relative path `/app1`, I am expecting it the URL to be `external.company.ca/app1` with content coming from `internal.company.ca/some_app`. Instead, the browser is going directly to `internal.company.ca/some_app`.

No 302 or anything, just straight there. This is odd to me, since `internal.company.ca` is not mentioned anywhere in the configuration except for the reverse proxy config, so I don't know how the browser is learning of the domain at all.

Here is a Fiddler capture from the client (browser) point of view showing the behaviour right after I click the link that goes to `/app1` (you'll have to trust me that the green names are `external.company.ca` and the black names are `internal.company.com` and the path is `/some_app/blahblah`):

[image]

Everything happening after this point is loading the page with `internal.company.com`. This won't work at all in production, of course.

The following is a (truncated) version of our Apache configuration files for consideration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # rewrite rules to 443
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName external.company.ca
    ServerAlias external.company.com

    # Logging rules.........

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none

    # Most of this is off for testing purposes, adding in case it matters

    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    # more SSL stuff.... Now on to the interesting part

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app1 https://internal.company.com/some_app
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 https://internal.company.com/some_app
</VirtualHost>
```

At one point, I thought that possibly the cookies were throwing things off since they were under different domains (.ca in front, .com in back), but I believe if the reverse proxying was working correctly, the browser would be none the wiser. Anyone see anything wrong with the above?

**UPDATE**

I found the culprit:

`<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign('https://internal.company.com/app1/login?redirectUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname + window.location.hash));</script>`

The problem is, how do I rewrite this absolute URL using Apache? I know mod_proxy_html modifies element attributes (such as `href` in the `a` element) but can it rewrite arbitrary data in an element itself?

The internal application was provided by a vendor, and although it may be possible to make modifications to it to remove code like the above, I would prefer to stay away from that path for now to see if there are alternatives.

Comment: If you view the raw html for the link, is the link saying <a href ="/app1"> or <a href="https://internal.company.com/app1>?  You may need to look into proxy_html (I think that's the module) to rewrite the HTML to remove references to the internal URL's (possibly depending on how much control you have with the site... sharepoint tends to be totally awesome for this)

Comment: The HTML is `<a href="/app1">`. 

There is also SSO happening here behind the scenes; internal.company.com is reading a cookie that contains authorization for the user. I'm thinking this is where things are falling down. I will look into proxy_html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a somewhat nasty work-around:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLLinks script src
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://internal.company.com
```

The problem is the use of absolute URL's throughout the HTML (and javascript) coming from the vendor's app. A search and removal of the domain solves the problem (but is incredibly slow).

If anyone has this problem in the future, **I do not recommend using this solution.** I'm guessing you're here because you can't modify the internal application. You should instead be sending in a ticket to whoever maintains the code to make their application more reverse-proxy friendly.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially safer solution would be the use of [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html). You could also consider [ProxyHTMLExtended](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlextended), but it can be quite brutal in its replacements, occasionally breaking JavaScript here and there.

Edit: Just noticed you're currently using ProxyHTMLExtended. My bad. As you've highlighted it is a pretty brutal and dangerous solution to the problem.